# How to share built-in wallpapers in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, personalization, sharing

For Pc's We can share built-in wallpapers very easily via file explorer: Windows>Web>Wallpapers  But for my Lumia 535 running windows 10 mobile it seems that built-in wallpapers cannot be shared. Similar is the case for ringtones. My question is that a can we share built-in ringtones and wallpapers via Bluetooth/mail or Windows 10 Mobile does not allow to do so? My phone is interop unlocked dual sim Lumia 535 (RM-1090) running W10M (14393.693) if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't share built in wallpapers of Windows 10 Mobile